# How to dynamically change pom.xml artifactId, name, scm connections

Tags: maven, pom.xml, mule4

I am creating a proxy template in mule 4 so our developers can easily create a new proxy with a jenkins job. But I am not sure how to change the artifactId, name, and scm connection values. My plan is to create a template repo in bitbucket and to dynamically change those values with an input of projectName from the jenkins job. The only thing I have found besides just using the xml path to change the value as a script is creating an maven archetype. Which works for artifactId and name, but not scm. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also what do you mean an archetype doesn't work for scm? Be specific and provide all the information. To avoid having an off topic question try to focus your question in a single issue, like this is my archetype but when I execute this command I get this error.